# First element does not have number and the number does not reset in new category

Tags: php, goutte

I tried to crawl this page:
http://hea.uum.edu.my/index.php/academic/current-student/convocation

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://hea.uum.edu.my/index.php/academic/current-student/convocation');


$step = array();
$i = 0;
$crawler->filter('.sppb-addon.sppb-addon-accordion')->each(function ($node) {
    global $step, $i;
    $step[$i]['item'] = array();

    $node->filter('.sppb-addon-title')->each(function ($node) {
        global $step, $i;
        $step[$i]['cat'] = $node->html();
    });

    $j = 0;
    $node->filter('.sppb-panel-heading > .sppb-panel-title')->each(function ($node) {
        global $step, $i, $j;
        $step[$i]['item'][$j++]['title'] = $node->html();
    });

    $h = 0;
    $node->filter('.sppb-panel-body .sppb-addon-content')->each(function ($node) {
        global $step, $i, $h;
        $step[$i]['item'][$h++]['content'] = $node->html();
    });

    $i++;

});

print_r($step);
```

It is almost perfect except for the fact that the first element for **item** doesn't have number and the numbering does not reset when in new array.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [item] => Array
                    (
                        [] => Array //here no number
                            (
                                [title] => STEP 1 :  ...
                                [content] => <p>If you are eligible to graduate...

...
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [13] => Array //here the number should be 0
                        (
                            [title] => STEP 14 : CONVOCATION DRESS ..
                            [content] => <p>Here are the official...
```

You can see the result here: view-source:http://convo18.uum.my/

Please help. And I interested to know if you have any elegant solution for this situation, on top of solving my problem.

Thanks for your time.

=========================================================================

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @NigelRen for the suggestion, here is the code that works:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://hea.uum.edu.my/index.php/academic/current-student/convocation');


$step = array();
$i = 0;

$crawler->filter('.sppb-addon.sppb-addon-accordion')->each(function ($node) use (&$step, &$i) {

    $step[$i]['item'] = array();

    $node->filter('.sppb-addon-title')->each(function ($node) use (&$step, &$i) {

        $step[$i]['cat'] = $node->html();
    });


    $h = 0;
    $node->filter('.sppb-panel-heading > .sppb-panel-title')->each(function ($node) use (&$step, &$i, &$h) {

        $step[$i]['item'][$h++]['title'] = $node->html();
    });

    $h = 0;
    $node->filter('.sppb-panel-body .sppb-addon-content')->each(function ($node) use (&$step, &$i, &$h)  {

        $step[$i]['item'][$h++]['content'] = $node->html();
    });

    $i++;

});

print_r($step);
```

Comment: Try defining $j and $j just after $i rather than in the middle of the code.  I would also learn how to avoid using `global` and look into `function() use() {` (in this case)

Comment: @NigelRen why don’t you put this as an answer? I’ll try your suggestion, am driving now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested a dummy setup and I think the solution is to define `$j` and `$h` outside any nested function.  The reason being that they are not defined at global scope so when you say `global $step, $i, $j;` and then `$j++`, this will take it as undefined the first time and then the post increment will set it to 1.  The test code to show this is...

```
$a = function() {
    global $c;
    echo "Value=";
    echo $c++;
    echo PHP_EOL;
};

$a();
$a();
```

outputs...

```
Value=
Value=1
```

Whereas...

```
$c=0;
$a = function() {
    global $c;
    echo "Value=";
    echo $c++;
    echo PHP_EOL;
};

$a();
$a();
```

Gives the desired output...

```
Value=0
Value=1
```

So define all of these at the start...

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$h = 0;
```

**Edit:**
Although as per my original comment, `global` is generally frowned on, it makes testing more difficult and also (as found) may not work as you expect.  The suggested method is to use the `function(...) use(...) {` method format, so in the example...

```
$c=0;
$a = function() use (&$c) {
    echo "Value=";
    echo $c++;
    echo PHP_EOL;
};

$a();
$a();
```

Comment: Actually I follow your suggestion to use ‘use’, and it works like a charm.. you can update your answer.. thanks for your help! 